# How to remove the dependence of Python extensions on the UCRT

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyinstaller, nuitka

I am using `cython` to generate `*.c` files, to be later compiled with the MS Visual Studio 2017 as `C/C++`. It all works splendid, with the minor exception that all python `*.lib` were dynamically linked. 
Since my goal is to produce a self-contained exe (large exe size is not a problem), I would like to ask if it is possible to static-link all the Python `*.lib`. I already tried specifying the `\MT` release option and defining all Python libraries on the Debugger include.

Unfortunately, all my efforts were futile, since the dynamically linked executable can't find the `python3.dll` when copied to another computer. Currently I plan to copy the Entire python install directory together with the executable and specify the proper include links when compiling.

Therefore, I am interested in any option, it it exists, to produce a self-contained portable executable.

I would appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Pardon my understanding, but how is this associated with the C++ language?  You talk about C files, but C is a different language.  Where's the C++ code for us to look at?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am sorry, I compile it as a C++ project in VS.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. It's going to be a lot trickier than you think.

Comment: Try compiling Cpython from source and then generate a static library.

Comment: @xaav why is this needed. I have *.lib files in my libs folder. It should be possible to static-link them.

Comment: Yes but libpython is not static.

Comment: @xaav yes I just found an explanation about that. The problem is that I useadditional of libraries like numy, uncertainties etc....It is not only pure python.

Comment: Then you're screwed. You would need to rebuild all of your dependencies and patch the import mechanism.

Comment: @xaav well I can also live with a dynamically linked exe, providing the fact that I can copy and execute it on another pc.

Comment: Then there are two options for this: nuitka and PyInstaller. The former has significantly better performance, but it is also much more difficult to get it to work. While nuitka literally compiles Python files (just like Cython), PyInstaller actually generates a self-extracting archive that then runs Python.

Comment: @xaav I already successfully used pyinstaller, the problem is that it still binds some libraries dynamically, and if they are not at hand on the new pc, nothing works. I was hoping that with visual studio I can avoid this.

Comment: The easiest way forward is copy the DLLs from the MSFT redistributable installer into your application directory. Unfortunately, due to the nature of Python internals, this (self-contained executable) is a very difficult problem to solve.

Comment: BTW, even if you got VS to work, you would *still* have the same problem. So even the proposed solution is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

xaav is correct.

I cannot comment so Instead I will post this as a solution in the hopes it will direct you to right path.

Cython exists for a reason.  You get your python code, add a few changes and bam, your code is cythonised.

This is good for two reasons.  To obfuscate the code and it can speed up the code (depends).

Why do you not use cython and pyinstaller?  This is tried and tested.  Pyinstaller even says that it supports it.  The approach you are taking can be done in theory but it is so overly complicated and not even needed.

Possible concerns:

But can't they steal my source code?  No, it's cythonised so yes but not easily.

Can't I use Nuitka?  Yes, if you want it to be buggy and not work as intended.

What about the libraries, they do not work on another pc?  Spec files exist for a reason.  A bit of manual handling and this can work.

Can't I compile to c++ and then make it standalone?  Take a look at the number of unanswered questions and people who could not get it to work.  Also, it is not needed when pyinstaller and cython exist and does the same thing.  Cython is widely supported.  It just feels like  you are doing things the long and hard way.

But won't compiling to c++ be easier.  No way, pyinstaller already does most of the leg work.  You might have to adjust the spec file here and there, but otherwise it's the only way to go.  Keep in mind it also has integration with pyupdater too.

Comment: cython works fine. The problem is, that I can't copy the executable to another pc. pyinstaller has similar problems, it binds some windows libraries and if those are not to be found on the new pc the binary fails.